# Change text of specific <a> text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `asp:Repeater` that makes a table with a few `<td>`s and `<tr>`s. In each of the `<tr>`s, I have an `<a></a>`.

Now, on a certain event I want to change just the `<a></a>` tag in the `<tr>`.

So, I want to do something like:

```
$("a").text("I changed!");
```

, but I only want to change the `<a>.text` in one `<tr>`, not all the `<a>` elements on the page.

I am experimenting with `.closest()`, but unfortunately don't know enough about jQuery to make this functional.

Comment: It would help if we could see more of your html structure.

Comment: How do you identify this `one <tr>`? Maybe post some markup, also http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have the target `tr` somehow, then you can use the following code to find the `a` tag inside that:

```
tr.find("a").text("text here");
```

How to find `tr` really depends on what context you are in and how your target `tr` is identified from others.

e.g. if it's the "first" tr you may say:

```
var tr = $("tr").first();
```

if it's the element that the event has happened for (e.g. click event):

```
var tr = $(this);
```

if you are in the event of a child element of target `tr` you may say:

```
var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the `<tr>` with an **Id** so that you could identify it and then change the containing

So for example you could mark your `<tr>` with id **'myid'**  and do something like this in jquery:

```
$("#myid a").text("I changed!");
```

Or if you dont want to mark it with an **Id** then, you could use selectors if you know which  it is.
For example getting the first  would be:

```
$("tr:first a").text("I changed!");
```

Some references:

- http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/